# Kali linux and opening sh files using script

Tags: python, pycharm, shortcut

Hello I have such a problem. I am  beginner and I would like to create a type of a shortcut to pycharm because I have to always go in /root/Downloads/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh to open it. Code which I build:

```
import subprocces
subprocess.call('cd /root/Downloads/pycharm/bin./pycharm.sh', shell=True)
```

Comment: For a shell script, you can write `bash /root/Downloads/pycharm/bin./pycharm.sh`

Comment: thank you very much